# Unable to access elements of vector<vector<?>>

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have this class where the only atribute is a vector<vector<?>> like this:

```
struct Pixel {
    float r, g, b;
};

class Test {
private:
  vector<vector<struct Pixel>> pixels;
public:
  void read(std::string filename);
}
```

The method read is where first I read data from a file and put in a 1d array:

```
std::vector<pixel> v;

while(getline(file, line_pixels)) {
  if(line_pixels.size() > 0 && line_pixels.at(0) != '#') {
    std::stringstream ss(line_pixels);
    std::string value;
    while(getline(ss, value, ' ')) {
      pixel p;
      p.r = p.g = p.b = stoi(value);
      v.emplace_back(p);
    }
  }
}
```

after that I transfer the data from this 1d vector to the 2d vector `pixels`. I have tried to do this in this 2 ways:

```
int index = 0;
size_t h = stoi(height), w = stoi(width);
for(size_t i=0; i<h; i++) {
  std::vector<pixel> row;
  for(size_t j=0; j<w; j++)
    row.push_back(v[index++]);
  pixels.push_back(row);
}
```

with this code, when I try access any element from pixels with something like `pixel[index]`, I got a segmentation fault error.

The other option I have tried is that:

```
size_t h = stoi(height), w = stoi(width);
pixels.resize(h);
for(size_t i=0; i<h; i++)
  pixels[i].resize(w);
for(size_t i=0; i<v.size(); i++) {
  int row = i / w;
  int col = i % w;
  pixels[row][col] = v[i];
}
```

with this code, I got an segmentation fault error in that resize line.

Anyone can tell me the correct way to do that?

**UPDATE**

full code is divided in this 2 projects: https://github.com/klebermo/codec contains the classes Netpbm and Bitmap where the read method is implemented. https://github.com/klebermo/game uses the methods from the previous link.

Comment: How large is `v`, what is its size? What are the values of `height` and `width`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `width` and `height` are read from the file, and `v` is a `std::vector` used to store the data from the file, using `v.push_back(...)` (it's the second piece of code in the question)

Comment: Please use a debugger to get their actual values, and then [edit] your question to show those values, and the value of `v.size()`, to us.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is the result of a debug session, displaying the content for `v.size()` and `row.size()` for a 32x32 file: https://pastebin.com/9kUL7iU3

Comment: I'm sorry, but the only useful thing shown by that dump is that the crash happens in `Netpbm::toArray`, in the file `src/netpbm.cpp` at line `10`. So it happens in t he code you *don't* show us, Please create a [mre]. And ***[edit]*** your question to show it.

Comment: Also please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Looks like your `Bitmap` object is invalid.

Comment: Oh, the dump also shows that you have a vector like `std::vector<Pixel, std::allocator<Pixel> >`, you attempt to call its `size` function (in `toArray`), but the vector have `this=0x0`. So you're using an invalid vector.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the 'line 10` is the access to `pixel[index]` i mentioned in the question. this is the `toArray()` method: https://pastebin.com/cZRnFjet

Comment: @molbdnilo Can you explain why you think the class is invalid?

Comment: the call-stack says that it happened when calling `std::vector<Pixel>::size` so it sounds like you corrupted the memory of the `pixels` vector somehow. I don't see it in the code you posted though. Maybe run it under valgrind or compile it with address sanitizer

Comment: @PeterT after compilation with address sanitizer, I got this output: https://pastebin.com/j3HHTpmi. running under valgrind, I got this: https://pastebin.com/caHHPfjP (edit: I did a second run with the address sanitizer, and got this result: https://pastebin.com/H044qCy8)

Comment: @KleberMota `this` when calling the vector's `size` is the null pointer. This often indicates being a member of an invalid object.

Comment: @PeterT the line 48 reported in the result from the run with the address sanitizes is the line `pixels.push_back(row);` in the code (in the second loop of the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like other people said the error is not in the code snippets you posted.
This is why people want a minimal reproducable self-contained code example, to narrow down the error.

The actual error (or one of the actual errors) is in this line:

```
float * vertices = image.toArray().data();
```

Written out in a more expanded form this expression means:

```
float * vertices;
{
    std::vector<float> temp = image.toArray();
    vertices = temp.data();
} // temp gets destroyed here, since it goes out of scope.
// accessing vertices after this point is undefined behavior
// because the memory it points to was deleted by the 
// destructor of temp
```

This means that the access to `vertices` after that one line cause undefined behavior, especially writing to it will corrupt other objects often times.

You can keep the vector around for the same duration as `vertices` to avoid this. Also, don't call `delete` on a pointer that was managed by a std::vector.

```
std::vector<float> vertices_vec = image.toArray();
float *vertices = vertices_vec.data();
```

This way `vertices` will keep pointing to valid data as long as `vertices_vec` does not go out of scope.

edit:

Additionally I guess the image read-in code doesn't have bounds checking in all cases, so if the input-file is invalid you might get additional issues there. So you could add some more assertions/debug checks with bounds-checking in there.

Edit2:

You are violating the one definition rule.

In one header (`Netpbm/src/netpbm.hpp`) you have

```
class Netpbm {
protected:
  std::vector<std::vector<pixel>> pixels;
public:
  virtual void read_file(std::string file_name) = 0;
  virtual void write_ascii_file(std::string file_name) = 0;
  virtual void write_binary_file(std::string file_name) = 0;

  int getHeight();
  int getWidth();
  std::vector<float> toArray();
};
```

and in another header (`Netpbm/include/netpbm.hpp`) you have

```
class Netpbm {
public:
  virtual void read_file(std::string file_name) = 0;
  virtual void write_ascii_file(std::string file_name) = 0;
  virtual void write_binary_file(std::string file_name) = 0;

  int getHeight();
  int getWidth();
  std::vector<float> toArray();
};
```

These two have different sizes, you are compiling parts of the code assuming one size and other parts of the code assuming the other size. Therefore corrupting the stack.
If the consuming code doesn't know the vector is supposed to be there, then the generated constructor will never initialize it, so you are accessing a vector that you never called the constructor on.

Comment: even with this change in the code, the same error continue to happen, reported in the same line than before. the output for the run with the address sanitizer, with the code compiled with the suggested change, is: https://pastebin.com/mDimiNnV

Comment: I don't really see a source of a very huge stack in there, maybe try increasing the stack size with the compiler option `-Wl,--stack,16777216` (this would set it to 16MB, which should be plenty) for testing. It might just be growing this large because of address sanitizer stuff

Comment: @KleberMota found another error (ODR violation), see my edit